# error in setting an apn in android application

Tags: android

I am working on an android application in which i want to set apn. Tried the code posted on stackoverflow,Can anyone guide me in this problem ?
Following is the code i used.I applied this code on button click..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
```

But how can i set the default apn in android application

Comment: are you working on ice cream Sandwich ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find more regarding to APN  on [GIT HUB APN ANDROID](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/573afdd74db101ee6f20f3bd1c9976648414c834/prebuilt/common/etc/apns-conf.xml)

and for your information   [WRITE_APN_SETTINGS not available on Ice Cream Sandwich](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24227)